# Can da-words be dropped when context is clear?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification, pronominal-adverb, context

> (Me)
> Wenn ich objektiv sein soll, sind die Hunde  meistens sehr groß und somit eine Gefahr. Ich kann　ein Beispiel geben:
>
> (corrected)
> Wenn ich objektiv sein soll, sind die Hunde  meistens sehr groß und somit eine Gefahr. Ich kann **dafür** ein Beispiel geben:

A German native speaker corrected me saying that I should put *dafür* in the final clause. I don't understand the reason for this correction. Shouldn't the idea that it is "for that" be implied from the context itself?

Answer (score 3):

I as a native German speaker can't see any reason to add *dafür*.

> Wenn ich objektiv sein soll, sind die Hunde meistens sehr groß und somit eine Gefahr. Ich kann ein Beispiel geben:

is perfectly fine and you are right: clear from context.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically there is nothing wrong with omitting the pronominal adverb *dafür*, but the sentence is stylistically more superior when you use it. You have a pair of two sentences here that belong together and complement each other. The first sentence (*dogs are big and dangerous*) is an introductory statement, while the second sentence (*there is an example*) is a conclusion. In this context, the pronominal adverb "dafür" is the glue that connects the two.

Of course, the statement of the second sentence is clearly understandable without this word, and the sentence is also grammatically correct, but when the word *dafür* is missing, one misses this nice glue that makes a smooth unity out of the two separate sentences.

Comment: I don't agree with the claim "the sentence is stylistically more superior when you use it". If there is anything to say about style here, it highly depends on context. But in the example given, I would tend to consider omitting the redundant word superior style.

Comment: I agree that the word "dafür" adds the idiomatic glue to the two sentences. Without this glue, the train of thought looks incomplete.